How to check whether a specific item of a l3-sequence is empty (blank) or not?
Like the title described, I defined a sequence,
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {;} {;2;3;4}

Obviously, \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {1} is empty (blank), but neither \tl_if_blank nor \tl_if_empty does not outputs as expected:
\tl_if_blank:nTF { \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {1} }
  { item~1~is~empty } { item~1~isn't~empty }
\par

\tl_if_empty:nTF { \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {1} }
  { item~1~is~empty } { item~1~isn't~empty }

The following is the MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {;} {;2;3;4}
\seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {1},
\seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {2},
\seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {3},
\seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {4}\par

\tl_if_blank:nTF { \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq }
  { item~1~is~empty } { item~1~isn't~empty }
\par

\tl_if_empty:nTF { \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq }
  { item~1~is~empty } { item~1~isn't~empty }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


You have to expand the argument, so \tl_if_blank:eTF. Also you are missing {1} in \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {1}

\tl_if_blank:nTF { \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {1} }

will always return false, because the argument contains three tokens.
You want to expand the argument before testing:
\tl_if_blank:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_seq {1} }

The function \seq_item:Nn is marked ★, which means that it works in e expansion. This expansions ends as soon as the actual item is delivered. For instance, if the first item in the sequence is \c_space_tl, the test will return false.
